# Is there a way to prevent AVPlayerViewController from updating the lock screen via MPNowPlayingInfoCenter?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, mpnowplayinginfocenter

here is my problem:
I've got an app playing audio files, updating the lockscreen info via `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo`, and this part is working fine.

But in an other view, i'm playing a video with `AVPlayerViewController` and `AVPlayer`, and when the video starts playing, it's updating the lock screen automatically, with nothing except the video duration.

I didn't find anything about this behaviour in Apple's documentation, I can't find a way to disable it.

So far, I've tried calling `UIApplication.sharedApplication().endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()` before the video starts playing, and `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()` after. It doesn't work.

Does anyone know a way to prevent this?

Comment: Update: I didn't find a proper way to fix it (below iOS10), so when the app gets in background, I'm pausing the video (which make it "invisible" to MPNowPlayingInfoCenter), and update nowPlayingInfo with the current song info.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with iOS 10 there is a `BOOL` property in `AVPlayerViewController` called **`updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter`**, that has the default value: `YES`. Just change it to `NO`:

```
//playerController is an instance of AVPlayerViewController
if ([self.playerController respondsToSelector:@selector(setUpdatesNowPlayingInfoCenter:)])
{
    self.playerController.updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!